# after installing magnus-ui in expo app getting error "No Space between hexadecimal literal and identifier"

Tags: react-native, expo

expo go giving me this error

> No Space between hexadecimal literal and identifier
> No Stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am facing same problem here but it just happen in Android, iOS is running with no problem

-- EDIT --

I just found the problem when I tried to run the project on browser.

So these are the steps for you reproduce my aproach:

Run:

`expo start`

Choose "Run in web browser"

You will face a error in "color" module:

Access the module directory and file:
node_modules/color/index.js

1st problem is in line 66:

change this:

`object &= 0xFF_FF_FF;`

to this:

`object &= 0xFFFFFF;`

2nd problem is in the line 258:

change this:

`lum[i] = (chan <= 0.039_28) ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;``

to this:

`lum[i] = (chan <= 0.03928) ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;`

So this solved my problem just creating a issue here:

https://github.com/Qix-/color/

-- UPDATE --

The right way to fix that is downgrade color plugin from 4.0.0 to latest release, in my case today (07/28) is 3.2.1 so run:

`yarn remove color`

`yarn add color@3.2.1`